# Where do I start to create a custom android control?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I would like to build a compound control for my Android app that can be duplicated to create an array of these controls that appears as a scrollable list in the UI.  Specifically, I want to create a control for an audio channel that has a volume fader, a pan knob, a mute button, and a solo button.  Then I would like to be able to automatically duplicate this control to make 16 or 24 channel controllers that show up in a list, like an audio mixer.

How is this best accomplished?  As of right now, **I plan to jump right in and create an extension of the View class**, which I assume will allow me to create a custom control.  However, I've never done it before and am looking for some confirmation.  Can someone please tell me I'm headed the right direction?  If not, please show me a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all discussed in official docs: [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)